# javascript on action error

Tags: javascript, jquery

after changing the select box it must collect checked check box ids and the submit it

```
$("#action").change(function(){
    if(($(this).val())!='0'){
        var data = { 'req_ids[]' : []};
        var doit = $("#action").val();
            $(".checkboxes:checked").each(function(){
              data['req_ids[]'].push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
            var size = Object.size(data['req_ids[]']);
                if(size>0){
                    $.post("workplan-requests.php?action=update&do="+doit, data);
                    $("tr.checked").remove();
                }
    $("#action").val('0');
    }
});
```

but when i select my action in select box by changing it,
it show this error:

```
TypeError: Object.size is not a function
var size = Object.size(data['req_ids[]']);
```

i know this error is because the java script run whole code at same time but how can i do this with out problem!?

Comment: what do you want to check with size?

Comment: i have to prevent post request to send empty data!!

Comment: then have a look at aruns answer, check of the array contains elements with .length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
var size = data['req_ids[]'].length;
```

Also try

```
$("#action").change(function () {
    if (($(this).val()) != '0') {
        var data = {};
        data['req_ids[]'] = $(".checkboxes:checked").map(function () {
            return this.id
        }).get();

        var size = data['req_ids[]'].length;
        if (size > 0) {
            var doit = $("#action").val();
            $.post("workplan-requests.php?action=update&do=" + doit, data);
            $("tr.checked").remove();
        }
        $("#action").val('0');
    }
});
```

Comment: Because `Object.size` is not a function. The `.length` of an array contains it's size

Comment: LOL!! this is because i defined the function on my other script `       Object.size = function(obj) {
           var size = 0, key;
           for (key in obj) {
               if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
           }
           return size;
       };` 
thank you guys.